# React-navigation navigates to the first item in the DrawerNavigator, instead of opening it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native , and have some problem with implementation of switch-stack-drawer navigation nesting by react-navigation . 
My nesting  navigations looks like this :

```
export default  SwitchNav =  createSwitchNavigator({
AuthLoading : AuthLoadingScreen  , 
LoginedStack : LoginedNavigator ,
AppStack : AppNavigator  
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
})

export const AppNavigator =  StackNavigator(
{
   Drawer : {
    screen : DrawerNav
  }, 
  Home: {
      screen:  Home   , 
  },
  Result : {
    screen: SearchResult
  } , 
  MyModal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
  } ,

});
export const LoginedNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
    Drawer : {
        screen : DrawerNav
    } , 
    LoginedHome  : {
        screen : LoginedHome  ,
    } ,     
    Result : {
        screen: SearchResult
      } , 
    MyModal: {
        screen: ModalScreen,
    } 
} )
```

And finally my Drawer navigation with independent routes ( none of them is in any stack navigators ) looks like this :

```
export default DrawerNav =  createDrawerNavigator({
SimpleScreen: {
    screen : SimpleScreen ,
  } , 
About  : {
    screen : About 
}
})
```

In LoginedHome and other pages I try to open this Drawer by :

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```

because of , as I understand in nested navigators `navigation.openDrawer()` is not accessible . 
The problem is , when I try to open Drawer it always navigate to first route in it (SimpleScreen) and opens Drawer in this screen . 
What  did I make  wrong? 
How do I have to implementing this kind nesting by using Switch and Drawer navigators together ?

I am really have made a lot of research , but cannot fix this or find any example/solution expect [githib question](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1122#issuecomment-331834172) which also have not any answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okai , after some research I did my solution , below how it was supposed to be :

```
export default  SwitchNav =  createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoading : AuthLoadingScreen  , 
  LoginedStack : DrawerNav,
  AppStack : DrawerNav  
},
{
 initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
})



export const AppNavigator =  StackNavigator(
{
  Home: {
    screen:  Home   , 
  },
  Result : {
     screen: SearchResult
  } , 
  MyModal: {
     screen: ModalScreen,
  } ,

 });
export const LoginedNavigator = StackNavigator(
{ 
 LoginedHome  : {
    screen : LoginedHome  ,
 } ,     
 Result : {
     screen: SearchResult
  } , 
 MyModal: {
    screen: ModalScreen,
 } 
 })

export default DrawerNav =  createDrawerNavigator({
SimpleScreen: {
   screen : SimpleScreen ,
 } , 
 About  : {
    screen : About 
 } , 
 Home : {
    screen : LoginedNavigator
 }
})
```